# send data to php using ajax post method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to pass data to php code using ajax. but I cant get is success.

```
<?php


$message = $_POST["message"];
 $buyer_name = $_POST["buyer_name"];
  $order_number =  $_POST["order_number"];
   $account = $_POST["account"];
    $designer = $_POST["designer"];
     
echo $message; ?>
```

this is my js code.

```
var formdata = {buyer_name:byrName,order_number:orderNum.trim(),account:account,designer:'admin',message:'testing'}
    
    if(autoMode){
            
        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',
            url: 'msgHandle.php',
            data: formdata,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function() {

                
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);


            },
            error: function() {
                alert('failed');

            }

        });
```

I have set a button to click and when clicked in runs this ajax code. the output is a alert with empty message. that means it success but seems like variables does not pass correctly to the php code. what is wrong in my code, I can't find.

Comment: Get rid of `processData: false`. That's only used when you're passing a `FormData` object, not a plain object.

Comment: Also delete `contentType: false`.

Comment: did it. but still getting empty alert

Comment: Put `var_dump($_POST);` in the PHP script.

Comment: And check the network tab in the development pane of your browser to check the correct data is being sent to your script

Comment: You should never be using `alert()` for debugging. Look into and learn the extreme usefulness of the web browser's devtools. Specifically Console, and using `console.log();`

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and found that by removing all the three parameters

```
 contentType: false,
 cache: false,
 processData: false,
```

From the code posts your data onto another page.

Tried for just a sample array.

[image]